# AWS IAM is failing with missing permissions that are unrecognized by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

A developer on our team is trying to view AWS CloudFront caching stats (https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v3/home?#/popular_urls and https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v3/home?#/cache) and is getting IAM permissions errors saying that he doesn't have `cloudfront:GetPopularURLs` and `cloudfront:ListCacheStatsDataPointSeries` permissions. I'm trying to give him access, but these IAM permissions don't exist in the IAM UI (see screenshots below). How can that be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70338590/1452257 worked so I'm guessing the actions exist, but haven't been added as possibilities in IAM. Good ol' AWS :)

Comment: Two devs reported the issue independently so I’m quite confident they actually got that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please give a try to this below into your policy file.

```
"cloudfront:Get*",
"cloudfront:List*",
```